# What does this 落实 mean here?

Tags: meaning

This is from an interview with a sports teacher.

记者： 王老师，您怎么好像在说我呢？ 我就不想虐待自己，所以很难坚持。
王老师： 怎么会是虐待呢？ 您以后联系我，我带你锻炼。 咱们有计划，有落实。

It looks to me like '咱们有计划，有落实。' means 'We have a plan and (we have) practical experience.'
Literally, 落实 says 'lower into reality'. It is a very succinct expression.

zdic.net has for [落实](http://www.zdic.net/c/d/a8/199529.htm)： （1） 使计划、措施、政策等得以实现 or (4) 实行

These don't really correspond to 'practical experience' which might be ‘实践经验’.

Maybe it should be 'We have a plan and (we have) the ability to see it through' or 'make it happen'.

Then 落实 translates 'the ability to see it through' which fits with (1) I suppose. 
Or am I totally wrong here? Is there some other meaning for '有落实‘ which fits?

Comment: 咱们有计划，有落实, we have a plan and execution.
落实=实现，达成，实施完成。

Answer (score 1):

> In 落实
>
> 落 = to implement
>
> 实 = actually / solidly

落实 (v): to (actually) implement; to (solidly) put into effect;

> *'咱们有计划，有落实'*

'有计划' means 'have plans (which need to be implemented)'

'有落实' means 'have implementation'

We can interpret this sentence as :

> "(first,) we'll have plans , (then) we'll have implementation (of these plans)."

*using the verb 落实 (implement) as a noun: 'implementation'*

or

> "(first,) we'll have plans , (then) we'll have these plans/ implemented."

More example sentence:

> 到最后，这计划并没有**落实** (At the end, this plan had not been **implemented**.)

Answer (score 1):

"落实" means implementing things inside a plan and try your best to reach the goal of that plan.

If you analyze 落实 from the very surface meaning,

`"落" means "drop"` （落下）

`“实" means "fruit"` （果实）

These words combined means that you do something meaningful and try to reach the practical and beneficial end. You can imagine that after watering and caring the apple tree for months, finally, you get get the apples dropped down when they are ripened. Finally, this word takes the meaning of this whole process, which is "do something for your plan and try to get the apple, a good result".

Go back to practical meaning. You have a `"计划" (plan)`, and finally, you need to `"落实" (apply)` it. This is a similar process to caring for an apple tree and tryin to get the apples from it.

For example, you want to get an 'A' in Chinese class, this is called “计划”, a plan

> (You have an apple tree and you expect to get an apple finally)

But if you never open the Chinese textbook after class, you never want to pay enough time on studying Chinese, then you didn't "落实"

> (You never water the apple tree and take care of it)

You didn't get anything from this plan`

> (You don't get any apple)

Another example, you want to date a girl/boy and `plan so many romantic things trying to reach her/him`, this is `a plan ”计划“`. And you did `reach her/him in the ways as you plan and talk with her/him`, this is `a "落实"`. Although you may not get her/him, you tried. You indeed "落实".

In your example, `"咱们有计划，有落实"` has a hidden sequence behind it.

We put `“计划” before "落实“` because you need to a plan firstly, then we are able to do something in action around this plan, just like the example above. 王教练 wants to say that he will give you a plan

> (Give you an apple tree)

He will take it in actions. For example, take this 王记者 with him to do exercises every day (They mentioned about 锻炼 (exercise)).

> (And I will water and take care of it with you, trying to get
>   an apple)

Comment: 有一支笔，有一个苹果！ :) A plan is an abstraction. Implementation is also abstract, it is a process, it is not a thing. That's why '有落实‘ confused me. "我来落实这个计划。“ "I will implement this plan." You are right, first comes the plan, then the implementation. （I will never get an A in Chinese!) You are saying '有落实' means 'we will get results (for you)'???

Comment: @Pedroski "有落实" means that "Follow this plan and do something meaningful in order to let the goal behind this plan come true". In my example, "buying an apple tree" is kind of a plan. "Watering and caring" is the implementation, with a goal to get the fruit finally. But please note that "落实“ doesn't mean you will get the result you want finally. What matters here is that you did try to implement it. Such as studying Chinese so hard to get an A but it may not come to an A, but you did 落实 your plan to get an A by studying hard.